# Repeat same data based on for each value in another table's column

Tags: sql

I have two data tables:

```
+---------+--------+                          +---------+
|Account  | Value  |                          | Version |
+---------+--------+                          +---------+
| 1       |  10    |                          |    a    |
+---------+--------+                          +---------+
| 2       |  20    |                          |    b    |
+---------+--------+                          +---------+
```

Basically, what I want to do is to add column "version" to the first table and repeat data for each version, e.g:

```
+---------+--------+---------+
|Account  | Value  | Version |
+---------+--------+---------+
| 1       |  10    |    a    |                       
+---------+--------+---------+               
| 2       |  20    |    a    |                
+---------+--------+---------+
| 1       |  10    |    b    |
+---------+--------+---------+
| 2       |  20    |    b    |
+---------+--------+---------+
```

Unfortunately, I can't hard-write the version names since they change very frequently, but data itself is static. Any idea how to do it with SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a `cross join`:

```
select t1.*, t2.*
from table1 t1 cross join
     table2 t2;
```

This produces a *Cartesian product* of the two tables -- which is exactly what your question describes.

Note that if either table is empty, this will return no rows.

Comment: Thank you! I totally forgot about cross joins and been trying to make the harder solution work the whole day.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in two ways:

First: by executing the below script you will have a table that you desired.

```
create table yourTableName as 
(select t1.*, t2.*
  from table1 t1 cross join
 table2 t2
)
```

Second:

- Add column version to table1 as nullable

  `alter table table1 add column version varchar(20)`
- insert combination data to table1

  `insert into table1 (Account, Value, Version)
  (select t1.*, t2.*
        from table1 t1 cross join
       table2 t2
  )`
- delete rows that version column is null

  `delete from table table1 where version is null`